# How do I plot more than two functions onto the same graph with very different ranges in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I can't find any info on how to do this on the Internet other than to use plotyy which only seems to work for two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Matlab documentation:

> **Use Right y-Axis for Two Data Sets**
>
> Plot three data sets using a graph with two y-axes. Plot one set of
>   data associated with the left y-axis. Plot two sets of data associated
>   with the right y-axis by using two-column matrices.

```
x = linspace(0,10);
y1 = 200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);
y2 = 0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);
y3 = 0.2*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);

plotyy(x,y1,[x',x'],[y2',y3']);
```

Comment: Is there a way to control the color though? It only returns two handles for the plots.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the way to do this that confers the most manual control is to create three overlapping `axes` with the plots you need, and only display the axis for the topmost one. You could even create 'empty' axes just so you they can serve as the only axis with defined 'limits' in the x and y axes.

Example:

```
ax1 = axes();
X1 = linspace(0,8*pi, 100);   Y1 = sin(X1);
plot(X1, Y1, 'r', 'linewidth', 10);

ax2 = axes();
h = ezplot(@(x) x .* sin(x), [-100, 100]); set(h, 'color', 'w');

ax3 = axes();
image()

%% place them on top of each other by calling them in the order you want
axes(ax3); % bottommost
axes(ax1);
axes(ax2); % topmost

set(ax1, 'visible', 'off');
set(ax2, 'visible', 'off');
set(ax3, 'visible', 'on');  % this is the axes who's limits will show
```

[image]

Comment: Well part of the problem is that one of the plots is on such a larger scale that the other three plots practically form a straight line on the bottom of the graph. I was just wanting some kind of automagic scaling.

Comment: This is exactly the point. All plots are independent because they sit inside independent axes which just happen to occupy the same space. You can call `axis` and set X and Y limits on each one individually to your heart's content.

Comment: (and if for whatever reason they don't happen to occupy the same space, you can manually specify this via the `position` property)

Comment: Is there a way to have it automagically set the x and y limits for each plot so I don't have to think about it?

Comment: @Noah depends what you mean by this. If you want the axis limits to be _optimal_ for each plot, then yes this is what happens by default. If you want the axis limits to be _identical_ for each plot, then no, since the axes are independent, you need to set their `axis` limits manually to be the same value.