# Matlab: Dynamic legend using plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot, legend-properties

I would like to plot two y-axes since I want to compare the results of my different simulations. Since my version in Matlab is 2015b, I think (as far as I read) that I need to use the `plotyy` command.

I have a problem with the legend and the right y-axis. Every time I run a simulation and plot it, the legend only shows the information of the first run, but for the other shows simply: "data 1", "data 2", etc.

On the right y-axis the values and the label are overlapping, as it shows in the image. This code has worked perfectly when I used `plot` only, but I am not sure with `plotyy` if I need to do something differently.

I would like help to properly display the legend and the right y-axis.

Output after 3 simulation runs:

[image: Plotyy after 3 simulation runs]

The code I am using for this:

```
% figure(41)

%Monthly average water production

monthly_water_average=[mean(water_month(1:745)) mean(water_month(746:1492)) mean(water_month(1493:2238)) mean(water_month(2239:2985)) mean(water_month(2986:3731)) mean(water_month(3732:4477)) mean(water_month(4478:5223)) mean(water_month(5224:5969)) mean(water_month(5970:6715)) mean(water_month(6716:7461)) mean(water_month(7463:8208)) mean(water_month(8209:8760))]; %% Buscar una manera de no hacerlo manualmente
figure (41);
location=parameter.weather.weatherfile;
location_name=location(max(strfind((location),'\'))+1:max(strfind((location),'\'))+6);
graph_text=[location_name ' PV:' num2str(parameter.pv.power) 'Wp ' ' Bat:' num2str(parameter.battery.cap) 'Wh '];

% set(hLine1y,'DisplayName','Days with precipitation');
% set(hLine2y,'DisplayName',text); 
title('Precipitation and average monthly water production')
xlabel('Month')
[hAxy,hLine1y,hLine2y]=plotyy(MonthNum,asmara_precipitation(:,7),MonthNum,monthly_water_average); hold all;
set(hAxy(2), 'YLimMode', 'manual');
set(hLine2y,'DisplayName',graph_text);
set(gca,'LooseInset',get(gca,'TightInset'))
legend('-DynamicLegend');
```

Comment: if you want absolute control, you can always not specify them as xlabels, and simply put rotated text using a `text(X,Y, MyString, 'rotation', 90)` command. Either on the same axis, or on an axis of its own. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876418/how-do-i-plot-more-than-two-functions-onto-the-same-graph-with-very-different-ra/43881254#43881254

Comment: Provide the code in the form of a [MCVE]